# Using a declared variable in the creation of an alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @PERIOD INT

SELECT @PERIOD = 1

SELECT @NUMERATOR / @DENOMINATOR * 100  AS 'Period 1'
```

Is it possible to instead of using `AS 'Period 1'` to instead use `@PERIOD` to replace the 1 in `AS 'Period 1'`

I was thinking something along the lines of `AS 'Period' + @PERIOD`
From the comments It appears this is not something that can not be done without dynamicSQL.

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Not without dynamic SQL; and you really don't want to do that for this. Sounds like a job for your presentation layer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does anyone have some tips on how I could better ask this question?

Comment: How many different periods?

Comment: I'm just stumbling across this question so I'm not the one to downvote or critique the question as originally posed. You probably weren't aware of technical terms like "column alias" and "dynamic sql" which is half the battle. I looked through the edit history and it made perfect sense to me. I'll leave the debate about the philosophy of SO to others. Rest assured that nobody likes to get beaten up for asking questions on here.

Answer (score 2):

A solution without dynamic sql may be like this:

```
DECLARE @PERIOD INT

SELECT @PERIOD = 1

declare @PeriodX as varchar(99) = 'Period ' +  cast(@PERIOD as varchar(9))
create table #t (c1 int)
exec tempdb..sp_rename '#t.c1', @PeriodX

insert #t
SELECT @NUMERATOR / @DENOMINATOR * 100

select * from #t
drop table #t
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DECLARE @PERIOD INT = 1

DECLARE @tmpExecVar AS NVARCHAR(max) =N'SELECT 1 AS [' + 'Period ' + Cast(@PERIOD AS VARCHAR) + ']'

EXEC(@tmpExecVar)
```